# How to dispatch an action based on a condition in side a router

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

How to dispatch an action based on a condition in the right way :
I do the following but i get a syntax error.

---

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
     <Route {...rest} render={props => (
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => user
          ?(
            store.dispatch(actions.login(user.uid));
            <Component  {...props}/>
          )
          :(
            store.dispatch(actions.logout());
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
              }}/>
            )
          )
        )}/>
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular parenthesis ( `(..)` ) let you return a value. This is why your syntax is wrong. You should do something like below.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  // return the Route component
  return <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {

        // run dispatch
        store.dispatch(actions.login(user.uid));
        // return component
        return <Component  {...props} />

      } else {

        // run dispatch
        store.dispatch(actions.logout());
        // return component
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />

      }
    });
  }} />  
}
```